# Azure media services - Issue with viewing an encoded video on IOS

Tags: ios, azure, video, encoding, azure-media-services

I have an Azure Web App. 
The end user can view video files in the application, both with and without encoding. 
Without encoding, everything works fine on all client devices-
The file URL in this case looks as following:

videojs: dispatching event: sourceset
     [{"src":"https://myAppName.blob.core.windows.net/myAppName/videoFileName.mp4","type":"video/mp4"}]

For encoding, we use the Azure media services.

In this case (with encoding), the file url looks as following:

videojs: dispatching event: sourceset [{"src":"https://myAppName.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/47686721654-6056-477190467269/5f4404565467771890ab66920d936327.ism/manifest","type":"video/mp4","techOrder":["azureHtml5JS","flashSS","silverlightSS","html5"],"protectionInfo":[{"type":"AES","authenticationToken":"provided"}]},{"src":"https://myAppName.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/47686721654-6056-477190467269/5f4404565467771890ab66920d936327.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)","type":"video/mp4","protectionInfo":[{"type":"AES","authenticationToken":"provided"}]},{"src":"https://myAppName.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/47686721654-6056-477190467269/5f4404565467771890ab66920d936327.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)","type":"video/mp4","protectionInfo":[{"type":"AES","authenticationToken":"provided"}]}]

When the end user tries to view this encoded video on iphone - IOS, it does **not** play successfully.
On Windows, it works well.

I read this article about url suffix needed to be added to video file url: specific suffix for each device, but I'm not sure this is the problem.

https://www.returngis.net/en/2014/11/microsoft-azure-media-services-testing-output-formats-in-live-streaming/

[image]

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try playing the videos in http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/ and see if that works. If you check Advanced, you will be able to specify specific formats.